# Do while loop won't break

Tags: visual-c++

I am making a Goldilocks game. If the user chooses the wrong answer it would loop back to the beginning of the program. When I try to choose any option it always loops back to the beginning including the correct answer which is 2. I am still new to c++. I do not understand why it is looping to the beginning if the condition is true when 2 is chosen.

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;




void FirstSet()
{
bool win = false;
string PName;
int choice;

int num1, num2, result;

do
{
    system("CLS");
    cout << " Please Enter Name \n";
    cin >> PName;


    cout << PName << " and the Three Bears\n\n ";


    cout << PName << " Walks up and sees 3 Doors, 1 Large Door, 1 Medium 
   Door and 1 Small Door. \n\n\n " << "Which Door do you want to Open?\n "
        << " 1 for The Large Door\n " << " 2 for the Medium Door\n " << " 3 
   for the small door\n ";
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == '1')
    {
        cout << " The large door is too heavy it will not budge.\n "
            << " Please Try Again\n\n ";
        system("pause");

    }
    else if (choice == '2')
    {

        win = true;

    }
    else if (choice == '3') {
        cout << " The Door is too small you would get stuck.\n "
            << "Please Try Again\n\n";

        }
    } while (!win);
}





int main()
{
    FirstSet();

    system("pause");
    return 0;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason none of your comparisons are turning true is because you are reading the input into an int variable. Then you are comparing to ascii character values of 1,2 and 3 which happen to be 49, 50 and 51 respectively. If you modify your if lines to compare directly with integers, it should work:

```
if (choice == 1)
{
 ...
}
else if (choice == 2)
{
 ...
}
else if (choice == 3)
{
 ...
}
```

Although, for readability purposes and also to avoid such cases, I recommend using switch case statements in this case.

Comment: Oh I see now, changing the comparisons to integers made the code work. I will switch to using switch case statements as you have suggested. Thank you for your time!